# How to determine if a string is located in AWS S3 CSV file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a CSV file in AWS S3.
The file is very large 2.5 Gigabytes

The file has a single column of strings, over 120 million:

```
apc.com
xyz.com
ggg.com
dddd.com
...
```

How can I query the file to determine if the string **xyz.com** is located in the file?
I only need to know if the string is there or not, I don't need to return the file.

Also it will be great if I can pass multiple strings for search and return only the ones that were found in the file.

For example:

**Query** => ['xyz.com','fds.com','ggg.com']
**Will return** => ['xyz.com','ggg.com']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "S3 Select" [SelectObjectContent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_SelectObjectContent.html) API enables applications to retrieve only a subset of data from an object by using simple SQL expressions.  Here's a Python example:

```py
res = client.select_object_content(
  Bucket="my-bucket",
  Key="my.csv",
  ExpressionType="SQL",
  InputSerialization={"CSV": { "FileHeaderInfo": "NONE" }}, # or IGNORE, USE
  OutputSerialization={"JSON": {}},
  Expression="SELECT * FROM S3Object s WHERE _1 IN ['xyz.com', 'ggg.com']") # _1 refers to the first column
```

See this [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) for an example with output parsing.

Comment: For some reason this does not work in my case. The WHERE condition returns nothing:{'Details': {'BytesScanned': 2473420329, 'BytesProcessed': 2473420329, 'BytesReturned': 0}}. If I remove the WHERE and use LIMIT 10, then I get the records as expected. What can cause the WHERE to fail? SELECT * FROM S3Object s where s._1 = 'xvz.com'

Comment: @realPro Try a broad wildcard pattern: `_1 LIKE %com% LIMIT 10`

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution was to add RecordDelimiter like this:  InputSerialization={"CSV": { "FileHeaderInfo": "NONE", "RecordDelimiter" : "\r\n" }}

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `aws s3 cp` command you can send the output to stdout:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket/foo.csv - | grep 'apc.com'
```

`-` The dash will send the output to stdout.

this are two examples of `grep` checking on multiple patterns:

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket/foo.csv - | grep -e 'apc.com' -e 'dddd.com'
```

```bash
aws s3 cp s3://yourbucket/foo.csv - | grep 'apc.com\|dddd.com'
```

To learn more about grep, please look at the manual: [GNU Grep 3.7](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)